# Change scrollbar style if it is at the top

Tags: html, css

I know it is possible to change a scrollbar using just CSS, but I wanted to remove the border radius of the scrollbar if it is at the top of its track. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.setting up `.myCss` class with pseudo `webkit-scroll` in the CSS.
2.adding `event Listener` on the window object with event of `scroll`
which gives me the `scrollY` position every time i scroll and saving it in `scroll`.
3.if scroll is equal to 0 add `myCss` Class. and if its not I am removing it.
`additions:` setting condition to change when it hits the bottom.

`firefox`:`window.scrollMaxY`

`chrome`:`document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight`

```js
        console.log(window.scrollMaxY)  //FireFox (Max Scroll Height)
        console.log(window.scrollY)   //(current Scroll Height)
        console.log(document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight)          //Chrome (Max Scroll Height)
window.addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
        let scroll = this.scrollY;
        if (scroll == 0) {
            document.body.classList.add("myCss")
        }
        else if(scroll==(document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
            document.body.classList.add("myCss")
        }
        else{
        document.body.classList.remove("myCss")
        }
    });
```

```css
p {
        background-color: aqua;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 300vh
    }


    .myCss::-webkit-scrollbar {
        background-color: gray;
        width: 10px;

    }

    .myCss::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Comment: Note that this only works on browsers that use the webkit engine

Comment: And that it doesn't really answer the question...

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but this doesn't answer the question ://

Comment: sorry i misunderstood the question.check the answer now

Comment: @UmairFarooq this worked. Any idea on how to do it for when it gets to the bottom? Do you just change the 0 to 100 in the javascript?